# Remove quotes from json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to remove the quotes from json object:

Using php, i get the data in the following format(display the data using console.log())

```
[
    ["Catching the Wind in Rural Malawi § SEEDM...", "3"], 
    ["Engineering § SEEDMAGAZINE.COM...", "2"], 
    ["Technology Review India: Nissan&#039;s Lea...", "2"], 
    ["Alternative Fuel Consulting & Technical Tr...", "2"], 
    ["MIT OpenCourseWare | Science, Technology, ...", "2"]
]
```

How to remove the quotes using jquery/json,I need string like this(no quotes around the number):

```
[
    ["Catching the Wind in Rural Malawi § SEEDM...", 3], 
    ["Engineering § SEEDMAGAZINE.COM...", 2], 
    ["Technology Review India: Nissan&#039;s Lea...", 2], 
    ["Alternative Fuel Consulting & Technical Tr...", 2], 
    ["MIT OpenCourseWare | Science, Technology, ...", 2]
]
```

Comment: You ought to accept an answer for your other questions.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 5):

You don't. You parse the JSON, convert them to integers, and then stringify again.